# What exactly do I do with the equ.traineddata file with Tesseract?

Tags: python, macos, tesseract, python-tesseract

What exactly do I do with the equ.traineddata file with Tesseract? I downloaded it from the Github repository. But when I go to execute my code, there is no difference from before the downloaded data. When I check in Terminal how many languages Tesseract is using, it only says 1 (English). I found the folder path of Tesseract, and drop the equ.traineddata file in there, but it is a Document file (versus and Exec file). I am not exactly sure what do. When I had the file in my desktop, I would call it with Python, but then I would get other errors that it couldn't locate the file. Can someone help me out?

I tried putting the file in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/5.3.1/lib.
```

But I am not sure if it is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `.traineddata` files directory (pretrained models) using `--tessdata-dir` param:

```bash
$ tesseract --tessdata-dir /path/to/tessdata/file/ --list-langs
```

[Docs here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/main/doc/tesseract.1.asc#options).

Comment: I get this error message: 

(base) Kevins-MBP-2:~ sterlingstories$ tesseract --tessdata-dir /path/to/tessdata/file/ --list-langs
Error opening data file /path/to/tessdata/file/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
List of available languages (0):

Comment: Well you need to replace `/path/to/tessdata/file/` with your the full path of `equ.traineddata`, for example `/opt/equ.traineddata`.